# Using selectors against a specific tag-attribute

Tags: css, css-selectors

I got a small problem with a webshop module. I'm not sure what's going on, but apparently the text I see on the website comes from a code such as a below (James).

Since I cannot find where they hid this code, i'm wondering if I can simply target the part where it says "james" with CSS, and change the layout that way around.

```
    <a id="bob" title="james">
```

**Edit:** To clarify: I'm trying to style (margins and whatnot) the part where it says "james".

Kind regards,
Dave

Comment: While this can be done, it seems kinda odd. Probably better to use a class.

Comment: I would, it I could locate the file/line in the module..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target attributes in css with this syntax: `[attr="value"]` So if you want to target `<a id="bob" title="james">`, you can use `a[title="james"]`

Comment: But you're styling the element itself, not the tooltip generated by the `title` attribute.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's trying to use the title attribute as the identifier, not as what he's trying to style.

Comment: I'm using the following:

---- a[title="Pago seguro con paypal"] {
border: 3px solid !important;
} -----

But doesnt seem to effect anything yet?

Comment: Hmm, in that case I guess what you said makes sense.

Comment: To clarify: I'm trying to style (margins and whatnot) the part where it says "james" in my first example.

Comment: Ah, well, apparently this code pulls the text from between the quotes, and displays that on the website. Is that even possible? So whatever is in the place of "james" in my first example, is what displays on the website.. IT SEEMS (but i'm quite a newbie..)

Comment: so you actually want to use CSS to take the title attribute and display it as static text on the page?

Comment: If I understand you correctly: yes. It's far from my first choice, but it would be a (temporary) solution. If it's even possible of course.

Comment: You can't do that with CSS.  It is fairly easy to do with javascript.

Comment: Hmm, I think i'll get back to finding the location of the code then.. Thanks a ton for the help and effort! I've learned something new at least :)